# How to create a global forecasting model using deep learning?

Tags: neural-network, regression, classification

I am aiming to build a global/general forecasting model (don't know what's the proper terminology) using deep learning. The idea behind this is to create a model trained on several time series that will allow me to obtain forecasts for the time series used during training and for others not used during training.

I think this is a mixed problem, classification-regression. If I am correct and this is a mixed problem then: How should I do it?

- Should I work only with the variable/s I aim to forecast (using lagged observations). I mean passing through the model in question (I think it could be a CNN-LSTM or a LSTMGC model) only the objective variable/s. If this is an option I would like to be explained or pointed to an explanation of how this model works and how should the data for the training be structured.
- Or should I pass to the model the categorical variables as well. Being in the case of "product sales" variables like region, type of product the categorical ones and sales or amount of selled items the variables to forecast. Regarding to this I have the same doubt as before. (In addition think this could be a model easier to interpret)

Will be of a great help if anyone could point to or explain to me if there is any methodology on how to solve this kind of problems using deep learning. Aspects like what are the most typical ANN structures to solve this kind of problem, how should the data be prepared and how should the model be trained.

Thanks in advance for all the help.
Original question posted in [Artificial Intelligence Stack](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38930/how-to-create-a-global-forecasting-model-using-deep-learning).

Comment: So do you have existing data where you know the answers that you can test your model with? We did a lot of forecasting using Excel and used past data to test the predictions.

Comment: @SolarMike I am aiming to use the typical methodology to train deep learning models, divide the data in train and validation sets (all know data). I assume the data should be in order, been the train data older than validation data. I don't know if this is the proper methodology for this kind of problem. This is one of the many doubts that arouse in my head when thinking about this. Maybe I should make this aspect implicit in the question.